# Polygonizer-master plugin in for QGIS 2.14

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, line

I have tried to download and install the Polygonizer-master plugin but this plugin is "Deprecated". I would like to know if there is another plugin with the same functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Polygonizer* plugin has become a core algorithm for QGIS and is called **Polygonize** as [mentioned by the author](https://github.com/p0cisk/Polygonizer/issues/8). You can find this in:

```
Processing Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools > Polygonize
```

Comment: @AngiolaFanelli - Most welcome, hope it helped :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Polygonize algorithm name gets translated when you use a non-English locale. For example, in French it is called `Mise en polygone`. Just in case you try the Processing search bar and don't find it...

Comment: @AngiolaFanelli, the best way to say 'thanks' is accepting the answer if it solved your problem. This will help other users to know that the solution by Joseph was the best solution.